# If an outer measure adds over two $\mu^*$-finite sets, does it add over subsets of those sets?

Tags: measure-theory

This question occurred to me when I was reading the definition of a [metric outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_outer_measure), but I couldn't think of an answer.

Let $X$ be a set and let $\mu^* : \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0,\infty]$ be an outer measure on $X$. Suppose that $E,F \subset X$ **are sets of finite outer measure** (Edited, in light of discussion in comments)  such that $\mu^*(E \cup F) = \mu^*(E) + \mu^*(F)$. If $E' \subset E$ and $F' \subset F$, does it follow that $\mu^*(E' \cup F') = \mu^*(E') + \mu^*(F')$? What if I also take $E$ and $F$ to be disjoint?

Comment: You should probably require $\mu^*(E \cup F) < \infty$ otherwise there are trivial examples as long as there exists at least one nonmeasurable set in $X$.

Comment: @UmbertoP: I see you are correct. Even if I throw in disjointness of $E$ and $F$. For example, in the case of Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$, I could find disjoint (nonmeasureable) sets $E',F' \subset [0,1]$ such that $\mu^*(E' \cup F') < \mu^*(E') + \mu^*(F')$ and then let $E = E' \cup (-\infty,0)$, $F = F \cup (1,\infty)$ to get disjoint sets $E$ and $F$ with $E' \subset E, F' \subset F$ and $\mu^*(E \cup F) = \mu^*(E) + \mu^*(F) = \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a counterexample for general outer measures. Let $X$ be a set with at least 3 elements $x,y,z$.  One can just use $X = \{x,y,z\}$. Define a finite outer measure $\mu^* : \mathcal{P}(X) \to [0,\infty]$ by
$$ \mu^*(E) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } E = \varnothing \\
1 & \text{ if } |E| =1 \text{ or } 2 \\
2 & \text{ if } |E| \geq  3 \\
\end{cases}.$$

Obviously $\mu^*$ is monotone, so the main thing is to see that $\mu^*(\bigcup A_n) \leq \sum \mu^* (A_n)$ holds. If the RHS is $\geq 2$, then this is trivial. If the RHS is $0$, then all the $A_n$ are empty, so the LHS is $0$ too. If the RHS is $1$, then exactly one of the $A_n$ has $\mu^*(A_n) =1$, and the rest are empty, so the LHS equals $1$ as well.

Let $E = \{x,y\}$ and $F= \{z\}$. Observe that $\mu^*(E \cup F) = 2 = 1+1 = \mu^*(E) + \mu^*(F)$. On the other hand, taking $A=\{x\}$ and $B = \{z\}$, one has $\mu^*(A \cup B) = 1$ and $\mu^*(A) + \mu^*(B) = 1+1 =2$.

---

**Added:** Relating to PhoemueX's answer, note that this outer measure $\mu^*$ is pathological in the following sense: there exist sets $E \subset X$ such that
$$ \mu^*(E) \neq \inf \{ \mu^*(F) : F \supseteq E, F \text{ is } \mu^*\text{-measurable} \}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer in the case of a general outer measure. But
most reasonable outer measures arise as in the Caratheodory construction
(cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath\%C3\%A9odory\%27s_criterion),
i.e. we have a (semi)ring $R$ of subsets of $X$ and a premeasure
$\mu_{0}:R\to\left[0,\infty\right]$ such that the outer measure $\mu^{\ast}$
is given by
$$
\mu^{\ast}\left(E\right)=\inf\left\{ \sum_{n}\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\,\middle|\, A_{n}\in R\text{ with }E\subset\bigcup_{n}A_{n}\right\} .
$$
The Caratheodory theorem then states that each of the sets in $R$
is $\mu^{\ast}$-measurable. Thus, using the definition of $\mu^{\ast}$,
it is not hard to see that for any $E\subset X$ with $\mu^{\ast}\left(E\right)<\infty$,
there is a $\mu^{\ast}$-measurable set $E^{\ast}\subset X$ with
$E\subset E^{\ast}$ and $\mu^{\ast}\left(E\right)=\mu^{\ast}\left(E^{\ast}\right)$.
In fact, we can take $E^{\ast}$ to be a countable intersection of
countable unions of sets in $R$.

Now, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu^{\ast}\left(E\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(F\right) & \overset{\text{assumption}}{=} & \mu^{\ast}\left(E\cup F\right)\\
 & \overset{E\cup F\subset E^{\ast}\cup F^{\ast}}{\leq} & \mu^{\ast}\left(E^{\ast}\cup F^{\ast}\right)\\
 & \leq & \mu^{\ast}\left(E^{\ast}\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(F^{\ast}\right)\\
 & = & \mu^{\ast}\left(E\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(F\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Since the first and last term coincide (and are finite!), we must
have equality in every step. Hence, $\mu^{\ast}\left(E^{\ast}\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(F^{\ast}\right)=\mu^{\ast}\left(E^{\ast}\cup F^{\ast}\right)$.

Now, $E'\subset E\subset E^{\ast}$ and $F'\subset F\subset F^{\ast}$,
so that we can assume $E,F$ to be measurable to begin with. Because
of
$$
\mu^{\ast}\left(E\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(F\right)=\mu^{\ast}\left(E\cup F\right)=\mu^{\ast}\left(E\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(F\right)-\mu^{\ast}\left(E\cap F\right),
$$
we thus see that $\mu^{\ast}\left(E\cap F\right)=0$ (note that the
above only holds since $E,F$ are measurable of finite measure). Thus,
by changing $E,E'$ and $F,F'$ by null-sets, we can assume that $E,F$
are disjoint.

Now, by definition of $\mu^{\ast}$measurable sets, we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu^{\ast}\left(E'\cup F'\right) & = & \mu^{\ast}\left(\left[E'\cup F'\right]\cap E\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(\left[E'\cup F'\right]\cap E^{c}\right)\\
 & = & \mu^{\ast}\left(E'\right)+\mu^{\ast}\left(F'\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
where the last step used the disjointness of $E,F$ which implies
$F'\subset F\subset E^{c}$ and $E'\subset E\subset F^{c}$.

As noted above, I am (like the OP) still very interested and unsure
about the general case of outer measures which do not come from a
premeasure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, +1. I also eventually discovered that the answer is "yes"  in cases where the outer measure can be approximated from the outside by measurable sets. So, basically, the answer is "yes" in all cases of interest. For general outer measures, this seems to be false. See my answer.

Comment: Very nice answer.